# How to specify virtual web hosts in Nessus (host header/SNI)

Tags: webserver, vulnerability-scanners, nessus

Say I have the web server `198.51.100.125` in Amazon cloud that I want to scan, which is hosting two domains `example.com` and `example.org`.

In Nessus, I have configured the targets like so:

```
198.51.100.125[example.com]
198.51.100.125[example.org]
```

This is so Nessus can send web requests with `host: example.com` and `host: example.org` when testing the two sites for vulnerabiliites, instead of scanning the default website. Ditto for SNI when using HTTPS.

However, the Nessus results are showing the web vulnerabilities on the reverse DNS host of `198.51.100.125`, which is `http://ec2-198-51-100-125.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` and `https://ec2-198-51-100-125.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` instead of the `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `http://example.org` and `https://example.org` sites.

I'm sure I've successfully done this previously, however it is not working this time.

What gives? Is there anything to check in configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a reply from Tenable Support:

> The issue you are experiencing seems to be and engine issue that looks
>   to have started in the 6.8 release, but this is something that will be
>   addressed in a future release.
>       this issue is being addressed at present. There was a number of systems that experienced this issue and we will be using yours as the
>   principle issue to develop the fix.
>       I currently do not have an ETA on the resolution deployment.
>       But i am assured it will be fixed in the future releases.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may have the format reversed.  According to [this post by the creator of Nessus](https://community.tenable.com/thread/1297), the format should be

```
example.com[x.x.x.x]
```

Comment: I _think_ I tried both ways round, as well as with hostname only (the hostname did actually resolve to the server I wanted to scan, but it ended up scanning the default site instead of the `example.com` binding).